# Can we integrate Aurelia with ElasticSearch datastore?

Tags: elasticsearch, aurelia

Anyone used Aurelia to fetch some data from ElasticSearch datastore? Is there any example project can I get for the same?

Comment: you can communicate with elastic seach using REST api. so you can do it using aurelia (or any other library of your choice). but keep in mind that you might want to block direct access from you clients directly to ES, and instead put some server of your choice in the middle. (because of security, business logic  and other considerations).